# Golang exec.Command returning nil error when exit code is not zero

Tags: shell, go

I'm trying to run a command in Golang, but it looks like it loses the exit code because the err is nil:

```
func runCommand() []byte, error {
  cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "KUBECONFIG=/tmp/.kube/config helm version")

  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

  stdOut, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }

  if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }

  bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdOut)
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }
  if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }

  fmt.Println(string(bytes))

  return bytes, nil
}
```

This return nil, even though the command returns with exit code != 0.

If I type:

```
$> /bin/bash -c KUBECONFIG=/tmp/.kube/config helm version
$<
$> echo $?
$< 0
```

If I type:

```
$> /bin/bash -c 'KUBECONFIG=/tmp/.kube/config helm version'
$< ...connection refused
$> echo $?
$< 1
```

So I tried to wrap the command in single quote:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "'KUBECONFIG=/tmp/.kube/config helm version'")
```

but then I get:

```
/bin/bash: KUBECONFIG=/tmp/.kube/config helm version: No such file or directory
```

(needless to say that /tmp/.kube/config is there, but I don't think the no such file or directory refers to that anyway).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: turns out I got it wrong. In fact I had two commands attempted and for some reason I was sure the one failing was the one I mentioned above, when instead the second command was exiting with a status code different from 0. The code works as expected and the err is not nil in case of exit code != 0. Sorry about that.

Comment: The command you’re running is `bash`, and that is exiting with `0`. Why not run `helm` directly?

Comment: JimB, the reason was so that I didn't have to split all the arguments in the command, and also I have some commands with pipes that I wouldn't know how to execute in Go. If I use the quotes in bash to run that `bash -c` command, the exit status is carried over. How can I achieve that from Go?

Comment: Looking at this more closely, you're not checking the error from the command, so how do you know it's not returning a non-zero exit status? Is the question actually about setting environment variables? It's much easier to just directly set them in the execution environment rather than dealing with shell parsing (and again, it's much easier to control what's happening if you don't shell out to `bash -c` at all)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've updated the original question. That was indeed a non-problem. The code return err != nil if the command terminates with exit status != 0. I had two commands running one after the other and got confused on which one was supposed to return err != nil. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you should be able to get it with `exec.ExitError`, see [exec package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#ExitError). Note that you may need Go 1.12. Here's a runnable example (but it won't give you realistic output at the go playground):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(`/bin/bash`, `-c`, `FOO=bar ls /foo`)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    stdOut, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error 1")
    }
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error 2")
    }
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdOut)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error 3")
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error 4")
        if exitError, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
            fmt.Printf("Exit code is %d\n", exitError.ExitCode())
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

On my system that prints:

```
$ go run main.go
ls: cannot access '/foo': No such file or directory
Error 4
Exit code is 2
```

If that doesn't work for you, maybe it's worth following @JimB's suggestion and invoking helm directly? The Go standard library should support pipes as well:

> It wraps os.StartProcess to make it easier to remap stdin and stdout, connect I/O with pipes, and do other adjustments.

([exec package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec))

Comment: Updated the question to not being an actual problem, but accepting this answer since you provided code to check exit code. Thanks